# Correct cron format

Tags: cron

So I wanted to execute two commands every every week at beginning of Friday 12am
and Sunday night 11:59pm before it turns Monday as I want this to be turned
on from friday-sunday night then again next friday-sunday and so on.

```
00 24 * * 5 screen -S skyblock -p 0 -X stuff "mangaddp default essentials.fly $(printf \\r)"
59 23 * * 0 screen -S skyblock -p 0 -X stuff "mangdelp default essentials.fly ${printf \\r)"
```

Comment: 24 is not an allowed hour.

Comment: so what format is correct for friday at 1am then?

Comment: Remember you can mark an answer as correct by clicking the checkmark next to it. (This is more useful than editing the title to include "solved".)

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor fix is required, as 24 is not a valid hour.

```
00 00 * * 5 screen -S skyblock -p 0 -X stuff "mangaddp default essentials.fly $(printf \\r)"
59 23 * * 0 screen -S skyblock -p 0 -X stuff "mangdelp default essentials.fly ${printf \\r)"
```

You can always refer to crontab(5) for more information about the format of your crontab.

Comment: so this will start at 12am friday morning and end 12 at night of sunday, well 11L59pm?

Comment: @user3123931 Yes